# How to save Firebase key for Swift in TableViewcell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner. The main function is that when user click a each button of cell, it will update data. But I just write a new data, it cannot update existing data.
**ViewController.swift**

This function write's a new key is not save existing key. How can I solve?

```
let  databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("location").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
        guard let firebaseResponse = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else
        {
            print("Snapshot is nil hence no data returned")
            return
        }



        let status = firebaseResponse["status"] as! Int

        let key = databaseRef.childByAutoId().key

        let up = ["id":key,
                  "status":status] as [String : Any]
        databaseRef.child("location").child(key).setValue(up)

        self.posts.insert(postStruct(status:status,key:key), at: 0)

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    })
```

**This my Exercise xcode in google drive**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2jj6V1tOGcVTm9JSy1uNV9fZnM

**This is firebase data for image:**

[image: This is firebase data for image]

Comment: Are you storing that autoId with your status data when you display data in tableCell? Show the where you are retrieving data from Firebase

Comment: if I do not use autoId ,how to use key to update ?

Comment: That autoId is your key so you need that to update your status value with it

Comment: I'm talking about this `childByAutoId()` it will create new autoId like `KHGx7IADzSquz7I8u` are you getting now?

Comment: `let key = databaseRef.childByAutoId().key
 
            let up = ["id":key]
            databaseRef.child("location").child(key).setValue(up)` I use this function it will write new key is not storing existing data for key

Comment: I'm saying it last time you need to show the code where you are retrieving data from firebase

Comment: Don't add code in comment, Edit your question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line

```
let key = databaseRef.childByAutoId().key
```

You are creating new `autoID` instead of using the current child autoId from `snapshot.key`, so change that line with below one and you all set to go.

```
let key = snapshot.key
```